# How to filter search query by multiple keyword

Tags: elasticsearch

current mapping in `test` index.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "tag_ids": {
        "type":"keyword"
      },
      "text": {
        "type":"text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

example documents

```
#1
{
  "tag_ids":["1","3"],
  "text": "example test"
},
#2
{
  "tag_ids":["1","2"],
  "text": "example test"
},
#3
{
  "tag_ids":["2","3"],
  "text": "example test"
},
```

now how to search document and filter the result by tag_ids?

if the document matched more tag_id, the score should be higher.

"match","term","terms" which to use?

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms":{
      "tag_ids":["1", "2"]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried terms, but all documents have same score 1.

can i treat tag_ids as text field, and different tag_ids as terms.

Comment: Based on the sum of tag_ids you want to give the score for the documents in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `bool/should` clause and add one term (or match) query for each tag id, you'll get the document #2 with the top score (since it contains both tag ids) and then documents #1 and #3 with a lower (but same) score since they both contain one tag id

```
POST tags/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "tag_ids": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "tag_ids": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Response =>

```
{
  "hits" : {
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.1817236,
        "_source" : {
          "tag_ids" : [
            "1",
            "2"
          ],
          "text" : "example test"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 0.5908618,
        "_source" : {
          "tag_ids" : [
            "1",
            "3"
          ],
          "text" : "example test"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : 0.5908618,
        "_source" : {
          "tag_ids" : [
            "2",
            "3"
          ],
          "text" : "example test"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: will this score consider the tf/idf issue of the tag?

Comment: What issue do you mean? The score is computed using the BM25 similarity which includes the TF and IDF components into the score.